# docker for static websites

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm starting using docker experimenting with simple static websites (just some html files, js and css);

I've succesfully created the container with nginx for it;
the first question is about how to make it work on the server; that is not clear to me; right now the solution i came up is to have nginx and docker installed on the server; I've used docker to run the container mapping port 5000:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:80 my_website_image
```

and using nginx directly on the server as reverse proxy to forward requests for my_website_domain to port 5000;
even if that works I guess is not the proper solution (isn't the purpose of using containers to not to have anything other than docker installed on the server machine?)

the second question is about deployment:
normally (prior to using docker) I was updating files locally, running rsync with the remote folder on the server and having changes online in a second;

right now with docker I have to make changes locally, rebuild the image, push the image, go to the server and pull the image, restart the container... Far more work to do for this simple task;
isn't possible to easily update files in the running container?
other than that I also don't want to necessarly use the docker registry since that will cost and I already pay to have git repositories for my code; so would be great a solution that makes no use of the docker registry;

any clarification would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to address this problem.

1. Mount a volume within your docker container from a remote file system (or your host).
2. Develop on a local nginx system, and only build the image when you're ready to deploy.

Remember, the idea of having a docker container is to ease deployment, not development.  The extent to which docker helps in development is the extent to which there are multiple services that are relatively independent that you need to deploy as a dependency to the work you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

@PaulProgrammer's answer is a perfect answer for the second question.

**For the first question:** if your system only contains this app, you can just expose 80/443 publicly. But if there are more apps that you want them listening to 80/443 too, you need reverse proxy. That reverse proxy can be installed on the system, or run inside another container.

I don't think the purpose of containerization is to abandon installing any software directly to the system completely. It just makes deploying and developing application much more easier, giving consistent behaviors when interact with different environments, reduce time of setting your application with its dependencies, even upgrade your application much more seamlessly.

In your case, your website image creates a HTTP server application container which serves your web application. You can ship this HTTP server application anywhere. Anywhere includes behind the reverse proxy of some environment.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Good catch.  The first question is fairly broad and opinion based.  It seems that there are a variety of models that containers are used within, from hybrid deployments through pure containerized to all kinds of bastardizations in between.  I don't pretend to know the "right" answer for any given use case, without digging into the problem at depth.

Comment: I agree. I rewrote the answer several times before submitting it. I am always fascinated seeing people adopt containerization to their app, env and, team. And I learn new things every times. As you said, it is up to use cases, anything to make things better not more complicated :)